# Python: Use Regular Expression to remove a character from string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

The whole file consists of lines like below.

```
\"ansText\" : \"11\",
\"boundsX\" : 0,
\"string\" : \"11\"
```

For any lines starting with `title`, I would like to remove the character `;` from the string after it. Below is an example of expected output

Input:

```
\"title\" : \"244442424268391(:)7)$(.:$?3.&!&3$83;767:2\",
```

Output:

```
\"title\" : \"244442424268391(:)7)$(.:$?3.&!&3$83767:2\",
```

I know how to set the regular expression to find the expression title by using:

```
 str0 = re.sub(r'\"title.*',"\"title\" : ",str0)
```

But I am not too certain how can I keep the original string but remove only one character.

Comment: This looks like JSON. Use JSON parser if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like so: `(\\"title\\" : \\".+?);(.+?\\")` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/iW8oY5/1)) and replace the string with regex groups number 1 and 2. This expression will look for strings containing `\"title\"` and a `;` character within it and use this information to create two regular expression groups, this given `\"title\" : \"244442424268391(:)7)$(.:$?3.&!&3$83;767:2\",`, the output would be:;

```
Group 1: \"title\" : \"244442424268391(:)7)$(.:$?3.&!&3$83
Group 2: 767:2\"
```

When you combine these 2 strings, you will get the result which you are after.

```
 str0 = re.sub(r'(\\"title\\" : \\".+?);(.+?\\")',r"\1\2", str0)
```

Comment: It will fails when there's more `;` than one. Right?

Comment: @KevinGuan: It should still do what you are after, however the first `;` (starting from the left) will not be included in the result.

Comment: That's what I meant, I thought OP might want remove all `;` from the string if there's more `;` in the string instead of just the first one.

Comment: @KevinGuan: Yeah I see your point. We'll see whatever the OP decides.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) and [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) without RegEx like this:

```
>>> str0 = r'\"title\" : \"244442424268391(:)7)$(.:$?3.&!&3$83;767:2\",'
>>> str0 = str0.replace(';', '') if str0.startswith(r'\"title\" : ') else str0
>>> str0
'\\"title\\" : \\"244442424268391(:)7)$(.:$?3.&!&3$83767:2\\",'
```